# Can a Windows 10 Enterprise machine be used as any other Windows 10 PC?

Tags: windows-10, desktop-computer

Simple question,

Does Windows 10 Enterprise function the same as Windows 10 Home or Pro? What I mean is, if I were to have a PC with Windows 10 Enterprise installed, would I be able to use it as, say, a gaming PC?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but why? There are features in Enterprise (and Pro) that are [not included in Home or Pro](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsforbusiness/compare) but are practically useless for non-business use.

If you're just going to be using the PC as a gaming machine you're better off with Home.

Comment: Win10 Enterprise also needs to be connected to and a member of an ActiveDirectory domain.

Comment: @Jeff A Windows 10 Enterprise computer does not have to be connected to an AD and be a member.

Comment: @Tekkie_Boy - That's not what our MS liaison tells us; that's why I made that comment. Ostensibly, it's because of the license management.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Windows 10 Enterprise and Pro does not have to be on the domain, but they can be. However Windows 10 Home can not be on the domain. This is the main difference.

Comment: @ZoranJankov - Yeah, I knew about Home v. Pro/Enterprise, but my organization was told that Pro v. Enterprise was the domain _requirement_ for Enterprise (that you and Tekkie_Boy are saying is false).

Comment: [Compare Windows 10 editions](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsforbusiness/compare)